# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Father.id_grandfather' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some table as below:

```
Grandfather(id_grandfather, nameGrandfather,birthdate) 
Father(id_father, nameFather, id_grandfather, birthdate) 
Son(id_son, nameSon, id_father, birthdate)
```

I want to select all of data Son, Father and Grandfather like the below view:

```
Son1    Father 1    grandfather1 
Son2    Father 1    grandfather1
Son3    Father 2    grandfather1 
Son4    Father 3    grandfather2
Son5    Father 4    grandfather2
```

So a created the model (mfamily.php) as below:

```
Class Mfamily extends CI_Model{ 
    function joinFamily(){
        $this->db->select('Son.id_son, Son.nameSon, Son.id_father, Father.id_father, Father.nameFather,Father.id_grandfather,Grandfather.id_grandfather,Grandfather.nameGrandFather'); 
        $this->db->from('Son', 'Father', 'Grandfather');
        $this->db->join('Grandfather', 'GrandFather.id_country = province.id_country');     
        $this->db->join('province','province.id_country = city.id_city');

        return $this->db->get();    
    } 
 }
```

In controller cfamily.php

```
Class Cfamily extends CI_Controller{    
    $this->load->model(‘Mfamily’);
    $data[‘family’]=$this->Mfamily-> joinFamily();
    $this->load->view(‘vFamily’,$data); 
}
```

My View vFamily.php

```
<html>
<body>              
    </tr>
    <?php if($family){ ?><?php
        foreach ($family as $row) { ?> 
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->Son.nameSon?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row->Father.nameFather?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->Grandfather.nameGrandfather?></td>
        </tr> 
        <?php }?> 
    <?php }else{ ?> 
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">Empty</td>
        </tr> 
    <?php } ?> 
</body> 
</html>
```

When I compile this source I get a message error as below:

```
Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Father.id_grandfather' in 'on clause' 
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\family\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

What's going on in my code?

Comment: You should edit this so that only code is in code syntax.

Comment: The text is a typo? `$this->db->select('Son.id_son, Son.nameSon, Son.id_father, Father.id_father, Father.nameFather,Father.id_grandfather,Grandfather.id_grandfather,Grandfather.nameGrandFather); 
        $this->db->from(Son, 'Father, 'Grandfather');`

Comment: Output the last query that is run because there is no Father.id_grandfather being used in the ON clause. Also FROM should only be from one table since you are using JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close  `$this->db->select();`. Check yourself.

```
$this->db->select('Son.id_son, Son.nameSon, Son.id_father, Father.id_father, Father.nameFather,Father.id_grandfather,Grandfather.id_grandfather,Grandfather.nameGrandFathe);
$this->db->from(Son, 'Father, 'Grandfather');
```

Comment: oh sory, actually i write the code as below:
>    Class Mfamily extends CI_Model{ 
>    function joinFamily(){
>        $this->db->select('Son.id_son, Son.nameSon, Son.id_father, Father.id_father, Father.nameFather,Father.id_grandfather,Grandfather.id_grandfather,Grandfather.nameGrandFather'); 
>        $this->db->from('Son', 'Father', 'Grandfather');
>        $this->db->join('Grandfather', 'GrandFather.id_country = province.id_country');     
>        $this->db->join('province','province.id_country = city.id_city');

>        return $this->db->get();    
>    } 
> }